# Superposicion de imagenes sin position:absolute

Tags: html, css

He intentado sobre posicionar dos imágenes, de ésta forma

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La lagrima es una imagen .png

Esta es la estructura html

```
<div class="intertTa">
    <div class="ta borderes ico">
        <img src="...">
        <img class="bad" src="/content/img/asesores/lagrima-asesor.png">
    </div>
    <div class="ta name"><span>Leonidas Segura</span></div>
    <div class="ta sale"><span>1,100</span><small>Ventas</small></div>
    <div class="ta price">
        <div><span>34,000</span><small>mxn</small></div>
        <div class="porcentajev">
            <div class="hakogreenini">
                <div class="item">1</div>
                <div class="itemTotal">47,450 <small>mxn</small></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

LESS

```
.ico {
                width: 104px;
                height: 104px;


                img {
                    width: 104px;
                    height: 104px;
                    z-index: 0;
                }
                /*.rules {
                    margin: auto;
                    position: absolute;
                    z-index: 2;
                    width: 104px;
                    height: 104px;
                    left: 0;
                    right: 0;
                    top: 0;
                    bottom: 0;
                }*/
                .bad {
                    position: absolute;
                    z-index: 1;
                    width: 22px;
                    height: 25px;
                    bottom: 29px;
                    left: 100px;
                }
            }
```

pero al mostrarlo en otros navegadores más básicos, la lagrima se va para arriba y no se queda en su lugar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

se pone mas o menos donde está el punto azul, quisiera saber de que forma puedo sobreponer la lagrima sin usar position: absolute o que puedo mejorar para que no suceda eso en navegadores muy básicos

Comment: `.ta.borderes.ico{position:relative}` y habrá que cambiar también lo de `left: 100px;` a algo más pequeño ya que tu imagen tiene `width: 104px`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

La propiedad [`position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/position) cuando se establece en `absolute` se posicionará usando las propiedades `left`, `top`, `right` y `bottom` con *relación a su [ancestro posicionado](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Containing_block#Identifying_the_containing_block) mas cercano*

> Un elemento posicionado es un elemento cuyo valor computado de `position` es `relative`, `absolute`, `fixed`, o `sticky`. (En otras palabras, cualquiera excepto `static`).

El valor `static` es el que tienen por defecto todos los elementos html. Eso significa que cuando pones `absolute` el elemento busca hacia arriba hasta llegar a la etiqueta `html` en el árbol del DOM cual es el primer elemento que tenga un valor de `position` distinto al valor por defecto y se posiciona **con respecto a este elemento**. En tu caso y hasta donde puedo ver no hay ninguno cercano por lo que se posiciona con respecto al viewport que es la raíz del árbol DOM. Esta foto te sirve para entenderlo mejor.

[image: jerarquia de elementos posicionados]

Fíjate en un detalle curioso y es que el elemento absoluto que es hijo de uno relativo se posiciona con respecto a este y esa puede ser tu solución ya que un elemento relativo que no se le especifique ningún offset **será posicionado pero se quedará en su lugar**, exactamente igual a un elemento estático. Con escribir

```
.ico {
    position: relative;
}
```

resuelves tu problema. Ten en cuenta que esto también puede alterar tu layout pues no conozco el contenido de tus otras clases pero por ahí va la solución. Especificar un contenedor que sea una de las filas de tu tabla para que las imágenes queden contenidas a cada fila.

La compatibilidad de esta técnica la puedes consultar [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Browser_compatibility) pero si te das cuenta hasta Internet Explorer 4 es capaz de manejarla.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la explicación